# Parent not allowing marriage to a converted Muslim because of perceived gossip; what is the ruling on this?

Tags: nikah, parents

I want to marry a recently converted Muslim woman, but my mother won't allow it. My mother believes people will talk bad about the family.

Should I obey her in this situation, or am I allowed to marry the woman?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Note that "Should I..." questions attract subjective answers which are a bad fit for the stackexchange betwork (off-topic). For further informations about our site and the stackexchnage model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. A Muslim man doesn't need anybodys agreement for marrying however it is better to take into account that your life would be more in harmony if you don't offend your parents.

Answer (score -1):

Females are not allowed to marry non-Muslim but if you are Muslim too. It is highly recommended to do so

[check this one](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/100148/a-muslim-woman-is-in-love-with-a-christian-man-and-wants-to-marry-him)

Comment: Did you read the question? The OP wants to marry a Muslim woman, she just happens to a revert.